# Problems in converting a given date to minutes

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

I have a function where I fetch date and convert it into milliseconds and then I change it to minutes. The final value is always positive but for some unknown reasons, the dates from Jun 5 to Jun 29 the resultant value is coming as negative. Because of this my subsequent operations which expect positive values get affected. What's the root cause of this problem ?. I have attached my piece of code with different snapshots of results for different dates. And can anyone suggest a workaround for this issue? I am using **java version "1.8.0_161"**

```
String democurrentDate = "Wed Jul 4 17:28:41 IST 2020";                    
Date entrydatecom = new Date();
entrydatecom = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(democurrentDate);
System.out.println("The current date in correct format for milli ==>" + entrydatecom);                    
int milli1 = (int) entrydatecom.getTime();
System.out.println("Milli === > " + milli1);
long minutesforcurr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milli1);
System.out.println("The minutes for current date is ==> " + minutesforcurr);
```

**When the date is July 4**

> The current date in correct format for milli ==>Sat Jul 04 17:28:41
>   IST 2020
>  Milli === > 431054184
>  The minutes for current date is
>   ==> 7184

**When the date is Jun 4**

> The current date in correct format for milli ==>Thu Jun 04 17:28:41
>   IST 2020
>  Milli === > 2134021480
>  The minutes for current date
>   is ==> 35567

**When the date is Jun 17**

> The current date in correct format for milli ==>Wed Jun 17 17:28:41
>   IST 2020
>  Milli === > -1037745816
>  The minutes for current date
>   is ==> -17295

**When the date is Jun 22**

> The current date in correct format for milli ==>Mon Jun 22 17:28:41
>   IST 2020
>  Milli === > -605745816
>  The minutes for current date
>   is ==> -10095

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "convert it into milliseconds". Convert it into what kind of milliseconds? Milliseconds since the Unix epoch? Milliseconds since some other epoch? Currently you're casting a `long` to an `int`, so you're almost certainly losing information there, and it explains why you're getting negative values. But we can't really help you without knowing what you expect the result to be and why.

Comment: Apart from casting to an `int` where a `long` is mandatory, you are the outdated datetime classes from `java.util`... use `java.time` instead of them.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`, `ZoneId`, `Instant` and `Duration`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use: `Long milli1 =  entrydatecom.getTime();`  
When you are casting a long to an int you are loosing a lot of data. 
an int number can support number between: -2147483648 and 2147483647
a long number is between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

By example if you are testing for "Wed Jun 17 17:28:41 IST 2020" the number of ms will be: 
1592407721000 ( > 2147483647 ) it can't fit

Answer (score 3):

You should use long, don't cast to int.

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

A major problem in your date/time string is that 4th Jul 2020 is `Sat`, whereas you have written `Wed` and therefore either it won't be parsed correctly or will cause exception to be thrown.

Apart from that, I recommend you use [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) instead of using broken `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

        // Parse to ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse("Sat Jul 4 17:28:41 IST 2020", formatter)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

        // Calculate duration in minute
        long minutes = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).until(zdt, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

        // Display
        System.out.println(minutes);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
24333
```